# Deploying wordpress as AWS lambda functions?

Tags: wordpress, aws-lambda

I am wondering if it is feasible to deploy wordpress as a series of lambda functions on AWS API gateway. Any pointers on the feasibility/gotchas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

PKK

Comment: Duh! Thank you Mark B.

Comment: Isn't there a NodeJS API for WP now? And RDBS services in tandem? It can definitely be done, but it's a huge amount of effort.

Comment: @PKK One way you could do this is using ` WordPress XML-RPC API ` There's a nice node package you can use [scottgonzalez/node-wordpress](https://github.com/scottgonzalez/node-wordpress) an example:  ` var wordpress = require( "wordpress" );
var client = wordpress.createClient({
    url: "my-site.com",
    username: "admin",
    password: "secret"
});

client.getPosts(function( error, posts ) {
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.end(posts.length);
}); `

Comment: Packaging PHP into Lambda via the AWS Blog (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/) and packaging the Wordpress code and configuration with it then exposing the REST-API sounds interesting. I'm wondering if this is even possible or is the overhead of the package going to swamp the response time.

Comment: The Laravel discussion at https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/ has some nice things to think about for my above comment. It makes me want to try this out with the API Gateway.

Answer (score 9):

You'll have a lot of things to consider with persistence and even before that, Lambda doesn't support PHP. I'd probably look at Microsoft Azure Functions instead that do support PHP and do have persistent storage.

While other languages (such as Go, Rust, Swift etc.) can be "wrapped" to run in AWS Lambda with relative ease, compiling PHP targeting the same platform and running it is a bit different (and certainly more painstaking). Think about all the various PHP modules you'd need for starters. Moreover, I can't imagine performance will be as good as something like a Go binary.

If you can do something clever with the Phalcon framework and come up with an easy build and deploy process, then maayyyybee.

Though, you'd probably need to really overhaul something like WordPress which was not designed for this at all. It still uses some pretty old conventions due to the age of the project and while that is all well and good for your typical PHP server, it's a different ball game in the sense of this "portable" PHP installation.

Keep in mind that PHP sessions are relied upon as well and so you're going to need to move those elsewhere due to the lack of persistence with AWS Lambda. You can probably find some sort of plugin for WordPress that works with Redis?? I have to imagine something like that has been built by now... But there will be many complications.

I would seriously consider using Azure Functions to begin with OR using Docker and forgoing the pricing model that cloud functions offers. You can still find some pretty cheap and scalable hosting out there.

What I've done previously was use AWS ECS (Docker) with EFS (network storage) for persistence and RDS for the database. While this doesn't carry the same pricing model as Lambda, it is still cost efficient. You can set up your ECS Service to autoscale up and down. So that way you're running the bare minimum until you need more.

I've written a more in depth article about it here: https://serifandsemaphore.io/how-to-host-wordpress-like-a-boss-b5993fcfbd8e#.n6fbnf8ii ... but it's basically just the idea of running WordPress in Docker and using EFS to offload the persistent storage issues. You can swap many of the pieces of the puzzle out if you like. Use a database hosted in some other Docker service or Compose or where ever. That part need not be RDS for example. Even your storage could be handled in a different way, though EFS worked pretty well! The only major thing to note about EFS is the write speed. Most WordPress sites are read heavy though. Your mileage will vary depending on your needs.

Comment: Honestly, your biggest cost with WordPress is likely to be your database which you aren't solving with AWS Lambda anyway.

Comment: With Lambda and Aurora Serverless this could change.

Comment: It could begin to change. Remember that PHP still isn't natively supported on Lambda. Then you still need a way to persist storage, S3 is viable with plugins, but all plugins installed will need to be managed by deploy and many admin functionalities won't work due to the lack of persistence. You can put assets on S3, but not other system stuff (plugins, etc.). Aurora Serverless will be a game changer in many ways.

Comment: For what it's worth, wordpress doesn't rely on PHP sessions.

Comment: That's part of a scale issue too. We ultimately had problems with both WordPress and Drupal years ago with UsMagazine site because sessions in the database. It was very difficult to scale and ultimately could not be used for such a high traffic site (with visitor login/commenting at least). A better place would be memcached/redis/etc. DynamoDB in terms of "serverless" ??? But that could require a bit of hacking. Hence why I think Aurora Serverless is the best thing that could happen to help this cause.

Comment: @Tom: Can WordPress use SQLite DB and solve the database cost?

Comment: Will it work with SQLite? I don't know, but can't imagine it would. Even if it did, there's just so much functionality missing that it wouldn't be a very reliable solution for the database. Aurora serverless is now a thing and things have evolved a lot. If I wanted to really try to use WordPress these days I might still go with EFS and serverless Aurora, and S3 for assets. Then use caching so the db was hit sparingly as it has a cold startup time cost (not major).

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes, anything is possible with enough time and effort. Is it worth it? That is a question best to ask yourself.

PHP can be run on Lambda as per the documentation located here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/scripting-languages-for-aws-lambda-running-php-ruby-and-go/ .

The bigger initial problem as stated in other comments is a persistent file system. S3 for media storage is doable via Wordpress plugin (again from the comments) but any other persistent storage for the request / script execution is the initial biggest hurdle. Tackle one problem at a time till you get to the end!